# Getting access to internal register of PCIe device

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've found few topics about it here, but none of them explained the issue I have.
I'm simply trying to get access to internal status register of PCIe device, by mapping it to user memory space in linux. 
Here is my system configuration:

```
# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.13-200.fc28.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 10 17:29:59 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Device 1980
       +-04.0  Intel Corporation Device 19a1
       <...>
       +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Device 19de

# cat /proc/iomem
df570000-df573fff : 0000:00:1f.2

# lspci -s 00:1f.2 -x
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 19de (rev 11)
00: 86 80 de 19 00 00 00 00 11 00 80 05 00 00 80 00
10: 00 00 57 df 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d9 15 69 09
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

So, the device is sitting on 00:1f.2 and visible for the system. I try to get access to internal "ERRCORSTS" register with offset 0x110 of memory controller, which shows the error status of individual correctable error sources on a PCI Express device *page1673* (here is the [manual for my SoC](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/c3000-family-datasheet.pdf) ). The output that I get from my program is:

**data = ffffffff**
**PCI BAR0 0x0000 = 0xffff**

It seems that I'm missing something in understanding of linux memory mapping or may be they just changed something in 4.18 kernel, so it's not so easy as it was before. 
Could anybody help me out with it, please?

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BASE_ADDR 0xdf570000
#define DATA_OFFSET 0x110
extern int errno;
int main()
{
    int i;
    int fd = open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    if(fd < 0) {
            printf("Can't open /dev/mem\n");
            return 1;
    }

    u_int32_t* mapped_base = (u_int32_t *) mmap(0, 4096UL, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, BASE_ADDR);

    // Trying to get access to device memory
    if(mapped_base == NULL) {
            printf("Can't mmap\n");
            return 1;
    } else {
            unsigned int status_register0 = *(int *)(mapped_base + DATA_OFFSET  );
            printf("data = %lx \n",status_register0);
    }

    // Trying to get access to DevID
    int fb = open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/resource0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);                   
    u_int32_t* ptr = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb, 0);
    printf("PCI BAR0 0x0000 = 0x%4x\n",  *((unsigned short *) ptr) );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I messed up the memory, when I experimented with it. So everything works after I reboot the machine.

Answer (score 2):

This performs pointer arithmetic.

```
mapped_base + DATA_OFFSET
```

The offset is automatically multiplied by the element size, which is probably 4 based on

```
u_int32_t* mapped_base
```

However, your documentation appears to specify offsets in bytes.

Thus, you need to read `0xdf570110` but are actually reading `0xdf570440`

Comment: Good point! I've changed DATA_OFFSET from 0x110 to 0x44, but still get the same result only '1's. As I read in bunch of articles, it should be fairly easy to map device memory space to user memory space by mmap() and work with it like with regular memory. And it's also strange, that /resource0 doesn't work either. But lspci -xxxx can actually read data from BAR0.
Is there some kind of protection in Fedora 28 Linux ?